# Existence of $\delta$ for a sequence of initial value problem, where sequence $f_{m}$ converges uniformly on compact subset of the domain.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $D$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $f_{m}$ be a sequence in $C\left(D ; \mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ that converges uniformly on compact subset of $D$ to $f_{0} \in C\left(D ; R^{n}\right)$. Let $\left(t_{m}, a_{m}\right)$ be a sequence in $D$ such that
$$
\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty}\left(t_{m}, a_{m}\right)=\left(t_{0}, a_{0}\right)
$$
for some $\left(t_{0}, a_{0}\right) \in D .$ For each $m \in \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$ let $x_{m}$ be a solution of
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d z}{d t}=f_{m}(t, x) \\
x\left(t_{m}\right)=a_{m}
\end{array}\right.
$$
I have to show that there exists a $\delta>0$ and $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\left[ t_{0}-\delta, t_{0}+\delta\right] \subset I\left(x_{m}\right)
$$
for all $m \geq N_{1}$, where $I\left(x_{m}\right)$ denotes the maximal interval of existence for $x_{m}$.

Can someone help me to solve this problem. I don't know how to approach or what theorem to use for this problem.